# how can i insert max() in my mysql?

Tags: mysql

im trying to use `max()` here in my `sql` but im confused because i am using `join` table and i dont have idea where i should insert the `max()`

i need to add the column name `date_issue` from the table `crew_documents_table`

here is my sql:

```
select * 
from
  info join
  crew_documents_table on info.id = crew_documents_table.document_crew_id join 
  crew_rank on info.crew_rank = crew_rank.crew_rank_id
where
  crew_rank in ('1','2','3','4','5') and
  crew_status = '$crew_status' and
  vessel = '$vessel_name'
group by full_name
```

Comment: `select *, MAX(crew_documents_table.date_issue) as max_date `

Comment: sorry i dont get it. can you re-write my sql and put it in the answer? thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your SQL query as below :

```
select *, MAX(crew_documents_table.date_issue) as max_date
from
  info join
  crew_documents_table on info.id = crew_documents_table.document_crew_id join 
  crew_rank on info.crew_rank = crew_rank.crew_rank_id
where
  crew_rank in ('1','2','3','4','5') and
  crew_status = '$crew_status' and
  vessel = '$vessel_name'
group by full_name
```

[MAX](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp) allows you to select the maximum date